# Vb Changing column index not displayed column index for gridview

Tags: vb6

Hi every one i have a problem which i need to change the index of my gridview. Not only displayed index. Cause i need it to populate into another document.

```
Dim haa As Int16 = DataGridView1.ColumnCount
DataGridView1.Columns(1).Index = haa - 1
```

I have tried this and it says Property Index is readonly.

Any idea how to make it dynamic so that ill be able to alter it ??

I have tried doing this too it works for displaying but when populating it does not work.

```
DataGridView1.Columns(1).DisplayIndex = haa - 1
```

Aside from this i tried this too
    DataGridView1.Columns.Move(DataGridView1.Columns["Total Of Field1"], haa -1);

However it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Every one i found a way to really shift shit out of a column. This is the way.

```
    Dim abc As DataGridViewColumn = New DataGridViewColumn

    abc = DataGridView1.Columns(1)

    DataGridView1.ReadOnly = False

    DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(1)
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(abc)
```

So i just take out the column i want to put at the last and append it back.
But i guess its a really bad way anyone has better idea ?